# how to make information on a separate line and the command on a new line in zsh?

Tags: zsh

I used zsh as my command line.

In my zsh, there is too much information (file path, git status) displayed, so that there is very little space for the commands that can be entered on each line.Enclosed by the red rectangle is the space where I can enter commands.

But I don’t want to remove the displayed information. Can I make the information on a separate line and the command on a new line when every time hit the enter?

when i `echo $PROMPT`, the result is:

```
%m %{${fg_bold[blue]}%}:: %{$reset_color%}%{${fg[green]}%}%3~ $(git_prompt_info)%{${fg_bold[$CARETCOLOR]}%}»%{${reset_color}%}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, ps1 accepts newlines like `\n`.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and add the result of: `echo $PROMPT`?

Comment: ok, I have added :)

Comment: In your question there's bash, in your tags there's bash and zsh and you say you use zsh. Decide - zhs __or__ bash? They are separate two things? `In my bash, there is too much information` So do you use bash __or__ do you use zsh?

Comment: I am sorry, I am a newbie in this area, and I don’t really understand the difference between them. I have corrected it. I use zsh

Comment: `zsh` has its own way of specifying colors with specific `%` placeholders; you don't need variables that contain raw terminal escape sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current bash PROMPT is;

```sh
%m %{${fg_bold[blue]}%}:: %{$reset_color%}%{${fg[green]}%}%3~ $(git_prompt_info)%{${fg_bold[$CARETCOLOR]}%}»%{${reset_color}%}
```

Lets add some [newlines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53789/whats-the-newline-symbol-in-zshs-ps1) (`$'\n'`) between those values;

```sh
export PROMPT="%m %{${fg_bold[blue]}%}::"$'\n'"%{$reset_color%}%{${fg[green]}%}%3~ "$'\n'"$(git_prompt_info)%{${fg_bold[$CARETCOLOR]}%}»%{${reset_color}%}"
```

On my local [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) PROMPT this generates:

[image]

<sub>(`MBP` is my local machine-name)</sub>

Comment: In Bash the PROMPT variable is nothing special, bash uses `PS1`, and bash does not interpret the `%{..` sequences.

Comment: You also don't need to export `PROMPT`; it's only useful for interactive shells, which source `.zshrc` on startup, so you can simply define `PROMPT` as an ordinary shell variable in `.zshrc`.